# Obfuscation of Kotlin Data Class' toString Method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-r8

I use Kotlin data classes everywhere in my app.

I am using R8 at compile time.

I have a security requirement where the generated `toString` method cannot contain the original attribute name. At the moment, the generated method, contains the entire classes attributes names in plain text and their obfuscated value names.

```
public String toString() {
    return "MyClass(id="+this.f1231msd+", password="+this.fj92313+")");
}
```

I have a few options but I would like to see if there are other options I have not found.

1. I checked Proguard's source code and found [this class](https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/blob/306338842db647095ddb78c62d9d480daa5281e8/base/src/proguard/obfuscate/kotlin/KotlinDataClassObfuscator.java) that uses the obfuscated name in the `toString` method. This would be perfect if R8 did this but doesn't seem to.
2. Manually override each data class' `toString` method with a blank string.
3. Write an R8 rule to step 2 for me
4. Create a compile time annotation to return a blank string for `toString`

Are there any other options out there?

Comment: 5. Get rid of the `toString()` calls, and see if R8 then removes the implementation as being unused. 6. File a feature request to have R8 handle this. 7. Write a Kotlin compiler plugin for the "override `toString()` with blank output" scenario.

Comment: 5. Good point. I reckon you're right. I use Timber for logging so perhaps R8 isn't stripping the implicit use of these classes `toString()` methods.
6. May just do that
7. Currently looking at implementing a redaction compiler plugin - https://github.com/ZacSweers/redacted-compiler-plugin
Thanks for coming back to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hunting around for other options and solutions, I decided to modify an existing compiler plugin that would automate this for me.

What this does is allows me to still benefit from Kotlin's auto-generated `toString()` method during development but then redacts the contents of `toString()` at release compile time.

It outputs a method such as this:

```java
public String toString() {
    return "██";
}
```

At the moment this is just on [my fork](https://github.com/StuStirling/redacted-compiler-plugin) in the branch `redact-all-and-class-names`